# Off the shelf host to bridge two USB serial devices?

Tags: usb, uart, serial, usb-host

I have two USB serial 'devices' (in the 'host' vs. 'device' sense) which I want to get talking to each other.

Is there a cheaper/smaller/more focussed off-the-shelf solution for a USB *host* that will act to bridge the two together than say some Pi or other SBC running all of Linux just for the sake of redirecting a couple of devices together?

I haven't had any luck finding anything, but I suspect I'm just lacking the right terminology.

Ideally this would take the form of a female type-A to male micro type-B adapter, but I could work with whatever. The device with the microUSB port is a 3D printer; the device with the male full-size type-A is a (programmer/USB-serial board for an) ESP-01. Each works independently, but after some trial I realised I'm an idiot and the reason they don't work together is that there's no host; simply using a microUSB so they fit is no good!

Comment: Even if such a device would exist, would it have drivers for all the USB serial adapter chipsets in the world? Basically you are asking what to buy, and you already mentioned Pi or other Linux SBCs and these would work if they have drivers for the particular USB devices, otherwise you need some Windows device.

Comment: @justme Er.. well I guess I didn't really think it through. Right. I was thinking SBC+Linux was way overkill for such a single purpose, but perhaps not so silly after all. Maybe there's a UART header I can use instead though, just skip USB altogether. Thanks.

Comment: If you think about it, this requires an application specific solution because both devices expect to be masters (or slaves) so there is no 1:1 translation. The bridge would need to be made to translate the messages between those specific masters (or slaves). Why stick with the ESP if you need a USB master? Might as well just replace it with an RPI. Or an MCU that can act as a USB master but drivers are a problem. Or if you're lucky your 3D printer is a virtual COM port and not native USB. Then you can just bypass the USB-UART bridge use an MCU UART. There are often tell-tale signs if it is one

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, you're right, just when I asked the question I thought surely there'd be like a $2  single chip board that does this, and I wouldn't need the Pi. As it is, I still might use the ESP because the old Pi I find might not have WiFi...

I don't need anything application specific though - the ESP itself is just a WiFi/serial bridge. I just need to get it to send through to the printer, and to receive and send back whatever acks/errors. Could also be a second ESP/whatever with USB host and programmed to relay devices to each other - i.e. what I thought might exist off the shelf.

Comment: Carefully inspect both devices (or find someoune elses teardown), it may well be that both devices have real UARTS and the USB-UART bridges csn be removed from both devices and the uarts then interconnected.

Comment: @Jasen You might be able to just plug in both devices to Windows and check the device manager to see if a virtual COM port is active.

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak Microsoft, what's a virtual com port?

Answer (score 1):

I've actually done something quite similar.

On a hardware level, you can do it with most recent microcontroller like PIC32, STM32 that contains 2 USB port that can be in host mode.

On the firmware level, it will be a bit tricky because you will need to code some logic for the data transfer and if I understand, you want to connect two host device together, thus the MCU will have to act as the master and initiate / handle transactions between both.

If they are both serial, and one of the slave actively sends the commands, and they are compatible, then it should be fairly easy and you just need to redirect the packets from one port to the other.

It's totally doable, but the amount of work might not be worth it if you can have it working with a raspberry, unless you take it as a learning experience.

Comment: Managed it in the end similarly to that, but with a single USB port (it was two devices, not two hosts) and communicated with the ESP01 over UART directly, without the FTDI board in the middle making it a USB device. Found an old mbed LPC1768 board I had which has USB D+/- pins that can be controlled as either a host or device. It's too slow to actually use (some combination of my rust embedded programming skills, and putting a wireless network in the middle of sequential commands that need to be ack'd) but a fun experiment.